# Model Class not referencing to Controller Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Model class/namespace is not referencing on my Controller class.

This was a MVC 4 code and I've tried .NET 6 and 3.1. Neither of them work.

UPDATE:

I have removed the screenshots as it was contributing to a question ban. The issue I was getting is that my model class was not referencing to my controller class. Having a bit more knowledge about the framework it was probably due to the fact that the framework package for either of the Classes wasn't compatible with the code or had different frameworks for different classes and was not compatible.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the screenshots as it was contributing to a question ban. The issue I was getting is that my Model class was not referencing to my Controller class. Having a bit more knowledge about the framework it was probably due to the fact that the framework package for either of the Classes wasn't compatible with the code or had different frameworks for different classes and was not compatible.